# arc nodes in tikz filling inconsistently

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple force drawing in tikz. Nodes placed on arcs have background filled; this is working on two of my three arcs. The first does show a colored background but it is behind the arc so the arc shows through. When I rearrange the order of the commands, it is still the first command executed that has the 'faulty' background.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}

\begin{document}

\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\tikz[scale=1.5]{
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
    \fill[black] (C) circle (4pt) node[above, outer sep=3mm] {$C$};
    \draw[very thick,->, >=stealth] (C) -- (180:3) node[above] {$BC$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->, >=stealth] (C) -- (216.8:3) node[below] {$CG$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->, >=stealth] (C) -- (-90:3) node[below] {$CF$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->, >=stealth] (C) -- (-58:3) node[below] {$CE$};
    \draw[very thick,->, >=stealth] (C) -- (26.6:3) node[above] {$CD$ };
    \draw[very thick, dashed] (C) -- (-0:3);
    \draw[thick, <->, >=stealth] ($ (C)+(2,0) $)arc (0:-58:2) node[fill = pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(199:2) $) {$\theta$ (known)};
    \draw[thick, <->, >=stealth] ($ (C)+(2,0) $)arc (0:26.6:2) node[fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(10:2) $) {$\alpha$ (known)};
    \draw[thick, <->, >=stealth] ($ (C)+(-2,0) $)arc (180:216.8:2) node[fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(335:2) $) {$\phi$ (known)};
}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You drew the label `$\theta$ (known)` (on the third line before the last one) before its arc which is at the last line. So, the order of labels should be fixed as follows (note that I exchanged `\theta` with `\phi` to keep the correct order of drawing the arc then its label on top):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}

\begin{document}

\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\tikz[scale=1.5,>=stealth]{
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
    \fill (C) circle (4pt) node[above, outer sep=3mm] {$C$};
    \draw[very thick,->] (C) -- (180:3) node[above] {$BC$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->] (C) -- (216.8:3) node[below] {$CG$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->] (C) -- (-90:3) node[below] {$CF$ (known)};
    \draw[very thick,->] (C) -- (-58:3) node[below] {$CE$};
    \draw[very thick,->] (C) -- (26.6:3) node[above] {$CD$ };
    \draw[very thick, dashed] (C) -- (-0:3);
    \draw[thick, <->] ($(C)+(2,0) $) arc (0:-58:2)     node[fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(335:2)$){$\phi$ (known)};
    \draw[thick, <->] ($(C)+(2,0) $) arc (0:26.6:2)    node[fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(10:2) $){$\alpha$ (known)};
    \draw[thick, <->] ($(C)+(-2,0)$) arc (180:216.8:2) node[fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] at ($ (C)+(199:2)$){$\theta$ (known)};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to calculate the positions for the nodes here. You can simply add them `midway` along the arc by adding `midway` to the node options.

You can also make the code more flexible and easier to understand by judicious use of scopes to avoid repeating style options for consecutive.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1.5,>=Stealth]{
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
    \fill (C) circle (4pt) node[above, outer sep=3mm] {$C$};
    \begin{scope}[very thick, ->]
      \draw (C) -- (180:3) node[above] {$BC$ (known)};
      \draw (C) -- (216.8:3) node[below] {$CG$ (known)};
      \draw (C) -- (-90:3) node[below] {$CF$ (known)};
      \draw (C) -- (-58:3) node[below] {$CE$};
      \draw (C) -- (26.6:3) node[above] {$CD$ };
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick, dashed] (C) -- (-0:3);
    \begin{scope}[thick, <->, every node/.style={midway, fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em}]
      \draw  ($(C)+(2,0) $) arc (0:-58:2)     node {$\phi$ (known)};
      \draw ($(C)+(2,0) $) arc (0:26.6:2)    node {$\alpha$ (known)};
      \draw  ($(C)+(-2,0)$) arc (180:216.8:2) node {$\theta$ (known)};
    \end{scope}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: auto-placed nodes on arcs]

If you wished, you could also make this more concise. However, this may make the code more difficult to understand rather than easier.

For example, the following is equivalent.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1.5,>=Stealth]{
    \draw [very thick, ->, fill] (0,0) coordinate (C) circle (4pt) node[above, outer sep=3mm] {$C$} (C) foreach \i/\j/\k in {180:3/above/{$BC$ (known)},216.8:3/below/{$CG$ (known)},-90:3/below/{$CF$ (known)},-58:3/below/{$CE$},26.6:3/above/{$CD$}} { edge node [\j, at end] {\k} (\i) };
    \draw[very thick, dashed] (C) -- (-0:3);
    \foreach \i/\j/\k in {+/0:-58:2/\phi,+/0:26.6:2/\alpha,-/180:216.8:2/\theta}
    \draw [thick, <->] ($(C)+(\i 2,0)$) arc (\j) node [midway, fill=pink, inner sep = 0.125em] {$\k$ (known)};
}
\end{document}
```